# How to build a drag and drop circle system like google+

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-effects, google-plus

I've been testing G+ for a little while and i find **the friends drag and drop into circle thing has a verry good effect** (don't you think ?)

I was wondering how to achieve a similar effect when drag & dropping user into a circle using jQuery. It may give me a starting point in order to achieve this for a tree or a square. :)

Thanks

Comment: jqueryui has a really nice [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)/[droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An opensource example of this is Circle Hack or Facebook Circles, source: https://github.com/voloko/facebook-circles
Which could be customized for your needs (unsure about licensing though)
It uses UKI.

If you want to achieve the same effect using jQuery I recommend using jQuery UI

Comment: Thanks, perfect place to start even if i didn't heard about UKI before.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this  http://www.9lessons.info/2011/09/google-plus-style-drag-and-drop-adding.html